# Finding the first four terms in each linearly independent solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

In the following problem I am trying to solve the given differential equation by means of a power series about a given point $x_0$. I need to find the recurrence relation which I know how to do but I am having trouble finding the first four terms in each linearly independent solutions.

$$y'' - y = 0, x_0 = 0$$

I have calculated the recurrence relation with no problems and got the following

$$ a_{n+2} = \frac{a_n}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$

It's finding the first four terms in each of the two linearly independent solutions I am having trouble with

Plugging in some terms to the recurrence relation yields the following

$$n=0 \rightarrow a_2 = \frac{a_0}{(2)(1)}$$
$$n = 1 \rightarrow a_3 = \frac{a_1}{(3)(2)}$$
$$n=2 \rightarrow a_4 = \frac{a_2}{(4)(3)}$$
$$n=3 \rightarrow a_5 = \frac{a_3}{(5)(4)}$$
$$n=4 \rightarrow a_6 = \frac{a_4}{(6)(5)}$$

So how do I use this to find the final answer. The answer I am looking for is the following but I am not quite sure how to find it,

$$y_1(x) = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!}+ \frac{x^6}{6!}+... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

$$y_2(x) = x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} +... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you've got so far is good. Just take it a bit further. For example,
$$a_4 = \frac{a_2}{4 \cdot 3} = \frac{\frac{a_0}{2 \cdot 1}}{4 \cdot 3} = \frac{a_0}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{a_0}{4!}.$$
Using this method of fully back-substituting, you should be able to get every term in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$. In the end, you should get a solution that looks like this:
$$y = a_0\left(\frac{1}{0!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \ldots\right) + a_1\left(\frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \ldots\right).$$
This means that the above two series will span the set of (analytic) solutions, which give you your two linearly independent solutions.

EDIT: It's not too difficult what I'm doing here. You already had $a_2$ in terms of $a_0$, and $a_4$ in terms of $a_2$. If you solve these equations simultaneously by substituting the expression for $a_2$ into the expression for $a_4$, you get $a_4$ in terms of $a_0$. Here's two more examples:
\begin{align*}
a_5 &= \frac{a_3}{5 \cdot 4} = \frac{\frac{a_1}{3 \cdot 2}}{5 \cdot 4} = \frac{a_1}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2} = \frac{a_1}{5!} \\
a_6 &= \frac{a_4}{6 \cdot 5} = \frac{\frac{a_0}{4!}}{6 \cdot 5} = \frac{a_0}{6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4!} = \frac{a_0}{6!}.
\end{align*}
Note that the evens and odds reduce down to $a_0$ or $a_1$ respectively. You only have to do $4$ of these terms! You don't need a formal proof that they follow a pattern.

That said, it's clear that they do follow a pattern. If you were interested in proving this pattern indeed holds, you could form an induction argument. Again, though, this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Could you show me the method of fully back substituting and getting the terms of a_0 and a_1 this is where I am confused

Comment: @jh123: Edited.

Comment: Okay I understand that much thanks! One last question, from that I see that you are getting everything in terms of $a_0$ and $a_1$ but then how are you find $\frac{1}{0!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}$ for $a_0$ and $\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}$ for $a_1$? Could you edit that in that will be my final question then I will fully understand the solution

Comment: The first term in the series is $a_0 x^0$, which is equal to $a_0 \frac{1}{0!}$ (I'm just rewriting to fit the pattern). You already showed that $a_2 = \frac{a_0}{2 \cdot 1} = a_0\frac{1}{2!}$, again rewriting to fit the pattern. Similarly, the second term of the series is $a_1 x = a_1 \frac{x}{1!}$, etc.